# OpenSSL - SSL incompatibility issue

Tags: ssl, curl

I've been querying an api for sometime using curl and all's been going well however recently the retrieval has stopped with the following error:

"An error has occurred: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.xxyyzz.com'

I contacted the api owner and have been told that this is likely to be due to SSL incompatibility and have been asked to update my OpenSSL. Does anyone know how to do this, I've restarted apache and the server but no joy so far?

Comment: Can you reveal the real api domain?

Comment: I'd rather not no, would that make a difference?

Comment: It's understandable if you don't want to publish the api domain here. THe reason I asked is that if we knew where to look (and it's publically accessible), someone could download their certificate and check the list of alternative subject names to confirm that the problem is on their end, or perhaps there is a different subdomain you need to use that we could notice in the cert.

Comment: How to go about updating OpenSSL depends on your OS.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and see if I can access their certificate. They are however confident it's a problem on my side. I'd love to restart OpenSSL to rule this out - I'm on linux, and haven't a clue how to go about this!

Comment: You could enter the domain name on a tool like [this](https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl) that will list all the domain names their cert is valid for.

Comment: It still depend on which flavour of Linux you're using. On Ubuntu, as an example, you would run `sudo apt-get install -y openssl` to update openssl and then restart Apache.

Comment: I'm running on a pretty standard linux server (Centos) with root access, do you know how I would restart this from here?

Comment: Reinstalled openSSL with - yum install openssl and it seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Cheers